# Infiniti G37 makes sizzling noise after driving in rain

Tags: noise, leak, infiniti, water, g37

After I parked my car in my garage after driving it in heavy rain, my car started to make a sizzling noise every few seconds. I have never heard this noise before. I was assuming it was the rain but what if something else is wrong? I searched it up and it said that something might be leaking. I don’t know what’s going on, can someone help me?

Comment: I know you've been here a few months, but welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! :o)

Answer (score 2):

Just a shot in the dark, but if you have a sunroof, you have a sunroof drain that includes tubing that runs down one of your door pillars and empties under the car. That drain could be dripping on a hot exhaust pipe or catalytic converter. That could make a sizzling sound.